# WPF send mouse and keyboard events into control or window

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, mouse

I have user control which is not displayed but is rendered into image and this image is displayed.
And I want send mouse and keyboard to this usecontrol (UC) and make it interactive.

That means if UC have buttons and mouse is over image where is button drawed and I click on it, it send mouse event to this UC.

Is it possible? If yes how?

I tried those codes, but without success:

```
public void mf_MouseButton_Left_Down(double x, double y)
    {
        System.Windows.Size size = new System.Windows.Size(1024, 512);
        UIElement element = this;
        element.Measure(size);
        element.Arrange(new Rect(size));
        element.UpdateLayout();

        int timestamp = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks).Milliseconds;
        MouseButton mouseButton = MouseButton.Left;

        MouseButtonEventArgs mouseDownE = new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, timestamp, mouseButton);
        mouseDownE.RoutedEvent = Control.MouseDownEvent;
        mouseDownE.Source = this;

        this.RaiseEvent(mouseDownE);
        element.UpdateLayout();
    }
```

---

```
    public void mf_MouseButton_Left_Down()
    {
        MouseButtonEventArgs mba = new MouseButtonEventArgs(
            Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0, MouseButton.Left);
        this.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(mba);
    }
```

Comment: Why aren't you just putting the usercontrol in the window rather than a picture of it? That seems the simplest way to satisfy your requirement.

Comment: @Andy Because I am trying use WPF as GUI for c++ 3D Engine. I and I like this way, the problem is I don't know how to do it. I have rendering partially done.

Comment: How are you hiding the UserControl to overlay it over the image? Are you just setting it's visibility to hidden?

Comment: @Tronald for now I have it inside window, and I hide a window after it is displayed. But in the end, it will be created only with code (something like this `UserContrl1 ^ UC = gcnew UserControl1` UserControl is classic C# WPF used in C++/CLI enviroment)